# ios status bar is about three times larger than ordinary one

Tags: ios, uistatusbar

I have to modify an ios app and the problem is that status bar(the bar with wifi icon and time things on top) is so big like three times larger than ordinary statusbar.

I'm doing nothing with statusbar in code .
...How can i fix this?

Comment: Are you sure its the status bar and not a navigation bar with no title, same color? Add a screenshot

Comment: are you running app in iOS7..?

Comment: Please share the screenshot and some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple: you have insert `UIViewController` in `UINavigationController` so, what you see is:

```
-------------------------
20 px StatusBar
-------------------------
44 px UINavigationBar
-------------------------
```

In iOS 7 they have the exactly same color.